# Loop through all nodes and wrap each word in a span if that word exists in a terms array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying to loop through all `nodes` and check if that node contains any of the items from `terms` array and wrap that words into span tags.

```js
function getAllTextNodes(element) {
  let node;
  let nodes = [];
  let walk = document.createTreeWalker(element,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  while (node = walk.nextNode()) nodes.push(node);
  return nodes;
}

const editor = document.getElementById('editor');
const allNodes = getAllTextNodes(editor);
const terms = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "definition": "A knowledge base is a published collection of documentation that typically includes answers to frequently asked questions, how-to guides, and troubleshooting",
        "expression": "knowledge base",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "definition": "Knowledge management (KM) is the process of creating, sharing, using and managing the knowledge and information of an organization",
        "expression": "knowledge management",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "definition": "this is test",
        "expression": "base",
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "definition": "management glossary item test",
        "expression": "management",
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "definition": "test",
        "expression": "Knowledge",
    }
]

allNodes.forEach(node => {
      if (node.parentNode !== null) {
        // Create New Node
        let newNode = document.createElement('p');
        newNode.innerHTML = node.parentNode.innerHTML;
        for (const term of terms) {
          if (node.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(term.expression.toLowerCase())) {
            const termNames = newNode.textContent.match(new RegExp("\\b" + term.expression + "\\b", "ig"))
            if (termNames !== null) {
              termNames.forEach((name, index) => {
                newNode.innerHTML = newNode.innerHTML.replace(newNode.textContent.match(new RegExp("\\b" + term.expression + "\\b", "ig"))[index], `<span class='hj-glossary-item' data-definition='${term.definition}' data-id='${term.id}'>${name}</span>`)
              })
            }
          }
        }
        // Update Node
        node.parentNode.innerHTML = newNode.innerHTML;
      }
    })
```

```html
<div id="editor">
  <p>Management is the reason why knowledge management is important. Knowledge base is also important to base.</p>

<p>Management is the reason why knowledge management is important. Knowledge base is also important to base.</p>

<p>Management is the reason why knowledge management is important. Knowledge base is also important to base.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid manipulating HTML directly, as you may alter the tags themselves (attributes, ...etc) instead of only the text.

You could:

- Create a map keyed by the expressions to find (lowercased) and with the term-objects as values. Sort it by descending length of the expressions, so that longer expressions get priority over shorter ones.
- Create one regex for finding all expressions (using `|`).
- Split the text of a text node by the matches (including the matches also)
- Iterate those to build a document fragment of new nodes, which will be a mix of `span` elements (for the matches) and text nodes (for the intermediate texts)
- Replace the original text node with this fragment.

Here is the implementation of that idea:

```js
function getAllTextNodes(element) {
  let node;
  let nodes = [];
  let walk = document.createTreeWalker(element,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  while (node = walk.nextNode()) nodes.push(node);
  return nodes;
}

const terms = [{"id": 1,"definition": "A knowledge base is a published collection of documentation that typically includes answers to frequently asked questions, how-to guides, and troubleshooting","expression": "knowledge base",},{"id": 2,"definition": "Knowledge management (KM) is the process of creating, sharing, using and managing the knowledge and information of an organization","expression": "knowledge management",},{"id": 3,"definition": "this is test","expression": "base",},{"id": 4,"definition": "management glossary item test","expression": "management",},{"id": 5,"definition": "test","expression": "Knowledge",}]

const termMap = new Map(
    [...terms].sort((a, b) => b.expression.length - a.expression.length)
              .map(term => [term.expression.toLowerCase(), term])
);
const regex = RegExp("\\b(" + Array.from(termMap.keys()).join("|") + ")\\b", "ig");

for (const node of getAllTextNodes(document.getElementById('editor'))) {
    const pieces = node.textContent.split(regex).filter(Boolean);
    if (!pieces.length) continue;
    const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
    for (const piece of pieces) {
        const term = termMap.get(piece.toLowerCase());
        if (term) {
            const newNode = document.createElement('span');
            newNode.className = 'hj-glossary-item';
            newNode.dataset.definition = term.definition;
            newNode.dataset.id = term.id;
            newNode.textContent = piece; // or = term.expression, if capitalisation must change
            fragment.append(newNode);
        } else {
            fragment.append(document.createTextNode(piece));
        }
    }
    node.replaceWith(fragment);
}
```

```css
.hj-glossary-item { background: yellow }
```

```html
<div id="editor">
<p>Management is the reason why knowledge management is important. Knowledge base is also important to base.</p>
<p>Management is the reason why knowledge management is important. Knowledge base is also important to base.</p>
<p>Management is the reason why knowledge management is important. Knowledge base is also important to base.</p>
</div>
```